# Chatter (publisher) canvas app: multisegment feed post?

Tags: chatter, canvas, publisher-action

In my canvas app, I can easily post to a chatter feed in this way:

```
Sfdc.canvas.client.subscribe(sr.client,
{
  name: "publisher.getPayload", onData: function (event)
  {
    var post = {};

    post.feedItemType = "LinkPost";
    post.url = url;
    post.urlName = urlName;

    Sfdc.canvas.client.publish(sr.client,
      { name: "publisher.setPayload", payload: post });
  }
});
```

- this posts a link item.

But how do I post a multisegment item? Apex/SOAP/REST API documentation segments of Salesforce.com have examples of posting such items; but is it possible with a simple Canvas API?

My ultimate goal is to post a text+link+inline image item, as Salesforce doesn't allow to attach preview images to link items (except for some of the whitelisted content providers).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following in [Posting to a Chatter Feed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_app_xhr_code_example_posting_to_chatter_feed.htm) using the Cross-Domain XHR client side proxy support.

```
var sr = JSON.parse('<%=signedRequestJson%>');
// Reference the Chatter user's URL from Context.Links object.
var url = sr.context.links.chatterFeedsUrl+"/news/"+sr.context.user.userId+"/feed-items";
var body = {body : {messageSegments : [{type: "Text", text: "Some Chatter Post"}]}};

Sfdc.canvas.client.ajax(url,
    {client : sr.client,
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(body),
        success : function(data) {
        if (201 === data.status) {
             alert("Success");
             }
        }
    });
```

Of note is how it does a more RAW AJAX POST to via the Canvas API in JavaScript.

With this, the problem is how to do a multipart/form-data POST via the Canvas ajax method. The [Chatter API: Examples, Best Practices and Tips](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Chatter_API:_Examples,_Best_Practices,_and_Tips) links to an [example multipart POST](https://gist.github.com/henriquez/2776843).

The source for the [Canvas ajax method is on GitHub](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceCanvasJavascriptSDK/blob/7e9969acaaeb9b1918badee80c2e2a6c4c3c6b58/js/canvas-all.js#L952).

Try switching out the `JSON.stringify(body)` with the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) instance.

At a very high level:

1. Add the first FormData for the normal JSON body. Se the Content-Type to application/json. See [Composing multipart/form-data with a different Content-Type on each parts with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535293/54026)
2. Append the next FormData entry for the attachment with the correct Content-Type.
3. Use the FormData as the `data` parameter to the Ajax request.

---

From [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5976031/54026):
*I'm aware that a the jQuery ajax method is a very different thing to the canvas ajax method, but it might provide some clues in the right direction around using the FormData.*

```
var data = new FormData();
jQuery.each(jQuery('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append('file-'+i, file);
});

jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'php/upload.php',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your post. There are 2 problems here, though:
1. You're basically using the REST API (just through the Canvas API ajax method), not the regular canvas API event flow;
2. The main problem is that if I use this method inside the canvas event flow (publisher.getPayload/publisher.setPayload), I'll get 2 chatter posts. I can surely get away from the regular event flow, but that would mean replicating the Submit/"Post to group"/etc. functionality of the publisher.
Not sure what to do here.

Comment: Thank you for the upload part, though :)

Comment: Just in case anyone's interested: https://github.com/mikebz/mikebz-node-canvas/blob/master/views/index.ejs - here's the app that demonstrates the approach.

Comment: It seems that there's no way to make a multi-segment post from within the getPayload/setPayload, so I'm going to reward this answer.

Comment: OK. Glad you found something useful in in :).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that currently the only way to make a multi-segment post is to use the REST API. I've created a post on IdeaExchange about supporting multi-segment posts with the regular canvas API, please vote for it:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LmYRQA0